# R Code Block in Org-Mode Doesn't Export the Resulting LaTeX Table to PDF

Tags: r, pdf, emacs, org-mode, ess

I am running the following R code in a code block in org-mode.

```
#+begin_src R :session :results output latex :exports results
  library(ggplot2)
  library(xtable)

  x <- rnorm(1000)
  g0 <- ggplot(as.data.frame(x), aes(x)) +
    geom_histogram(); g0
  hist_dat <- ggplot_build(g0)$data[[1]]
  hist_dat <- hist_dat |>
    select(xmin, xmax, count)
  print(xtable(hist_dat, digits = c(0, 1, 1, 0)), include.rownames = FALSE)
#+end_src
```

This creates the expected LaTeX code:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrr}
  \hline
xmin & xmax & count \\ 
  \hline
-3.3 & -3.1 & 1 \\ 
  -3.1 & -2.9 & 1 \\ 
  -2.9 & -2.6 & 0 \\ 
  -2.6 & -2.4 & 5 \\ 
  -2.4 & -2.2 & 7 \\ 
  -2.2 & -1.9 & 14 \\ 
  -1.9 & -1.7 & 11 \\ 
  -1.7 & -1.5 & 20 \\ 
  -1.5 & -1.3 & 35 \\ 
  -1.3 & -1.0 & 49 \\ 
  -1.0 & -0.8 & 64 \\ 
  -0.8 & -0.6 & 67 \\ 
  -0.6 & -0.3 & 108 \\ 
  -0.3 & -0.1 & 90 \\ 
  -0.1 & 0.1 & 98 \\ 
  0.1 & 0.3 & 85 \\ 
  0.3 & 0.6 & 84 \\ 
  0.6 & 0.8 & 62 \\ 
  0.8 & 1.0 & 59 \\ 
  1.0 & 1.3 & 35 \\ 
  1.3 & 1.5 & 32 \\ 
  1.5 & 1.7 & 22 \\ 
  1.7 & 1.9 & 25 \\ 
  1.9 & 2.2 & 13 \\ 
  2.2 & 2.4 & 10 \\ 
  2.4 & 2.6 & 1 \\ 
  2.6 & 2.9 & 1 \\ 
  2.9 & 3.1 & 0 \\ 
  3.1 & 3.3 & 0 \\ 
  3.3 & 3.6 & 1 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

However, when I run `org-export-dispatch` and select `export to LaTeX` and `As PDF file and open`, I get nothing in the PDF (neither code nor the results). I wonder what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: This was caused by a setting in `.Rprofile` that I had enabled to fix printing of `tibbles`. Once this was commented it out, this code works fine.